# Make a ToS Open a Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a modal appear after the user has agreed to the ToS.

Someone helped me with some code to make a button appear only after the checkbox is ticked to agree to the ToS. After the user agrees to the TOS, I'd like a modal to pop up stating that the user is leaving the site for another site.

```
$(":checkbox").on('click', function(){   $('.proceed').toggleClass("checked"); });
.proceed{   display:none; } .checked{   display:block; }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <input type="checkbox"> I Agree to the <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>. <br> <button id="myBtn" class="proceed">Open Modal</button>
```

and then I found some code on making a modal. I realize that I'm a bit out of my league here but I cannot seem to get the two to work together. Can anyone please help? Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}


$(":checkbox").on('click', function(){
  $('.proceed').toggleClass("checked");
});
.proceed{
  display:none;
}
.checked{
  display:block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  padding-top: 100px; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>


<input type="checkbox"> I Agree to the <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>.
<br>
<button id="myBtn" class="proceed">Open Modal</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean if user checked ToS then modal will popup?

Comment: Yup! That's what I'd like to do!

Answer (score 0):

Try onchange event in checkbox, Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}


$(":checkbox").on('click', function(){
  $('.proceed').toggleClass("checked");
});
.proceed{
  display:none;
}
.checked{
  display:block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  padding-top: 100px; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="tos" onchange="changeTriggered()"> I Agree to the <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>.
<br>
<button id="myBtn" class="proceed">Open Modal</button>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function changeTriggered() {
  let tos = document.getElementById("tos");
  console.log(tos.checked);
  if(tos.checked) {
   modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    $("#tos").change(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {

            setTimeout(function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
            },100)

        }
    })
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```css
.proceed{
  display:none;
}
.checked{
  display:block;
}


.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  padding-top: 100px; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Open Modal if ToS is checked</h2>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<input id="tos" type="checkbox"> I Agree to the <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>.
<br>
```